# Pyspark - how to initialize common DataFrameReader options separately?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm reading data with the same options multiple times. Is there a way to avoid duplicating common DataFrameReader options and somehow initialize them separately to use them on each read later?

```
    metrics_df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
        .option("driver", self.driver) \
        .option("url", self.url) \
        .option("user", self.username) \
        .option("password", self.password) \
        .load()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define all your options for **`dataframereader`** i.e.`<class 'pyspark.sql.readwriter.DataFrameReader'>` then add **dbtable** option to reuse the dataframereader.

**`Example:`**

```
metrics_df_options = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
        .option("driver", self.driver) \
        .option("url", self.url) \
        .option("user", self.username) \
        .option("password", self.password)

type(metrics_df_options)
#<class 'pyspark.sql.readwriter.DataFrameReader'>

#configure dbtable and pull data from rdbms table
metrics_df_options.option("dbtable","<table_name>").load().show()
```